# ~FIREFOX~ Selenium Instagram Bot is unable to locate Follow button to follow profiles despite trying By. XPATH, LINK_TEXT, CLASS_NAME etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, instagram

I am on VS Code and my Selenium Instagram Bot's intentional design is to read from a list of profiles from a .txt file, visit those profiles, follow and like a specified number of their posts(if they are private, it just follows them) then goes on to the next profile in the list, all the while using different pre-made bot accounts who's usernames are also on a list, so the code may iterate over them once a number of profiles have been engaged with by a single bot.
I am able to iterate over target profiles, but right now I am just having problems with locating elements and having them to be clicked by the bot. I got it to work on 1 profile, after going to the next profile, it simply didn't do anything and seems to can't find the follow button to click again(I can't recreate this, after some changes were made lol, just getting back into Python after briefly touching on it in school). I still haven't even seen the bot like a post too. Although, the XPATHS on the Log In and the Pop Ups seems to work. It's now just not interacting with the profiles.
~
Any insights would be highly appreciated!

Source Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time, random
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


profilePath = (r'C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\75d4lwz2.3rd')
options = Options()
service = Service('geckodrivere.exe')
firefox = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=service)
wait = WebDriverWait(firefox, 20)

file = open('scrape_archivepages.txt', 'r')
data = file.read()
igUsers = data.split('\n')
file.close()

file2 = open('botlist.txt', 'r')
data2 = file2.read()
bots = data2.split('\n')
file2.close()

def startLogIn(user_, pass_,):
    firefox.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

    
    while True:
        try:
            cookiesAccept = firefox.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]')
            time.sleep(4)
            cookiesAccept.click()
            time.sleep(4)
            break
        except:
            pass



    username = firefox.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
    password = firefox.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input')

    username.click()
    username.send_keys(user_)
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))

    password.click()
    password.send_keys(pass_)
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))

    log_in=firefox.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]')
    log_in.click()
    time.sleep(5)

#    while True:
 #       try:
  #          credentials= firefox.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Not Now"]')
   #         time.sleep(3)
    #        credentials.click()
     #       break
      #  except:
       #     pass

#    while True:
 #       try:
  #          notifications = firefox.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Not Now"]')
   #         time.sleep(3)
    #        notifications.click()
     #       break
      #  except:
       #     pass

def interact(igUserLink, n):
    firefox.get(igUserLink)
    time.sleep(2)

    #while True:
     #   try:
    follow = firefox.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#mount_0_0_0I > div > div > div > div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x10cihs4.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div.x9f619.xnz67gz.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1uhb9sk.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.x1q0g3np.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1qughib > div.xh8yej3.x1gryazu.x10o80wk.x14k21rp.x1porb0y.x17snn68.x6osk4m > section > main > div > header > section > div.x6s0dn4.x78zum5.x1q0g3np.xs83m0k.xeuugli.x1n2onr6 > div._ab8w._ab94._ab99._ab9f._ab9k._ab9p._abb3._abcm > div > div._ab8w._ab94._ab99._ab9f._ab9m._ab9o._abb0._abcm > button > div > div')
    time.sleep(2)
    private = firefox.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/main/div/div/article/div[1]/div/h2')
    if(bool(private)):
        print('lol')
        follow.click()
        time.sleep(2)
##xpath of header from IG saying profile is private
    if (not(bool(private))):
        print('here')
        follow.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        time.sleep(2)
        c = 0
        numPosts = firefox.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[1]/div/span/span')
        numPosts = int(numPosts.text)

        if n == 0:
                #do nothing
            if n <= numPosts:
                media = firefox.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/main/div/div[2]/article/div/div/div[1]/div[1]')
                media.click()
                time.sleep(1)
                like = firefox.find_element(By.NAME, 'Like')
                next = firefox.find_element(By.NAME, 'Next')
                while(c<n):
                    like.click()
                    time.sleep(3)
                    c=c+1
                    next.click()
            #break
        #except:
            #pass

    

            
def VibeFinderInteract(listOfBots, passw, userLink):
    
    for userbot in listOfBots:
        startLogIn(userbot, passw)

        for u in userLink:
            interact(u, 2)
            print('')

VibeFinderInteract(bots, 'samepasswordforallthebots', igUsers)
```

Comment: Error produced
(Im so confused it seems impossible, unless IG is cracking down on Selenium finding Follow buttons): 
""
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {#the copied CSS Selector from the Follow button#}
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:182:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:394:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:275:16

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you try `follow = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located( (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "...")))` ?